# Flux UndefVarError: `setup` not defined

Tags: machine-learning, julia, flux.jl

I have the following issue when running the following code,

```
hparams = HyperParams()

gen = generator()
enc = encoder()
dec = decoder()

gen_opt = Flux.setup(Flux.Adam(hparams.lr_gen), gen)
enc_opt = Flux.setup(Flux.Adam(hparams.lr_enc), enc)
dec_opt = Flux.setup(Flux.Adam(hparams.lr_dec), dec)

losses_gen = []
losses_dscr = []
train_steps = 0
# Training loop
gen_ps = Flux.params(gen)
enc_ps = Flux.params(enc)
dec_ps = Flux.params(dec)
...
```

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: `setup` not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(xWARNING: both Losses and NNlib export "ctc_loss"; uses of it in module Flux must be qualified
::Module, f::Symbol)
   @ Base ./Base.jl:31
 [2] top-level scope
   @ ~/github/AdaptativeBlockLearning/examples/MMD_GAN/mmd_gan_1d.jl:65
```

I am using Julia `v1.9.0`, and Flux `v0.12.10`. Can someone indicate to me what the new way of defining the optimizer is, and in which version of Flux has it changed?

Comment: You are using the old version of Flux. Try to update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, updating the Flux version to Flux `v0.13.17` the setup functionality is accepted.